# Forcing Maven2 to download source jars to local repository

Tags: maven-2, dependencies

I have my company dependencies (including non-FOSS third party stuff) in a Nexus repository, including source jars (downloaded with `mvn dependency:resolve`), where available.

I would like to have the source jars (and javadoc jars) download to my local repository (`~/.m2/repository`) so that I can go "offline".

I tried various combinations of `mvn dependency:resolve dependency:go-offline -Dclassifier=sources`, but it does not seem to copy them to my local repository.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you try:

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing I tried, but I did not list it in my question. It downloaded the JAR files to the Nexus repository, but not to ~/.m2/repository. I am trying to open the source code in IntelliJ (it shows ~/.m2/repository as the default location). I know that I can download the source separately, but if it automatically ends up in my local repository, IntelliJ will open it automatically.

Comment: @Ralph Sorry for asking but are you sure you don't get the sources artifact in your local repository? I don't understand why you wouldn't get them locally (Nexus should just act as a proxy). This is IMO unexpected.

Comment: I just checked my local repository for bcmail-jdk15 (BouncyCastle) and the bin jar is there, but the source file is not. My POM.XML depends on that library. The nexus repository DOES contain both.

Comment: Never mind (as Gilda Radner would have said :-)). I was looking in the wrong directory. It's on my local repository. Thanks.